# how to request to twitter using a keyword with a space?

Tags: api, twitter

I want to make a request to Twitter for a keyword that has a space in it. So i want to do http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=land rover.

How do i do this?

Comment: Er I rolled this back. I like saying hello.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use URL encode:

http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=land%20rover

Answer (score 2):

Like this: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=land%20rover

Answer (score 2):

Try http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=land%20rover.